# Multiple post slide in on page with Slider revolution

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

i'm using **revolution Slider** with visual composer in wordpress and i have an issue, i can't resolve.
I try to add 2 post-based sliders in one page but it didn't work. My first slider just show the load spinner and my second one didn't show at all.
This 2 sliders are based on a same template but they have 2 differents shortcodes.
Here is the code of my page :

```
[vc_column el_class="sous-titre-site"]
[rev_slider_vc alias="slider-actualite" title="Actualités" el_class="sous-titre-site"]
[/vc_column][/vc_row]
[vc_row css=".vc_custom_1484839039158{margin-top: 25px !important;margin-bottom: 25px !important;}"]
[vc_column]
[rev_slider_vc alias="agenda" title="Agenda" el_class="sous-titre-site"]
[/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

I have nothing in my console too, no error or something...

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out : i duplicate slides template inside those sliders and that causing some kind of conflict. I just have to create another slider and thats it.